# How do I show the average by month in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there a possibility I can find the average per month (30 days) of a count sum column in a pivot table? If I use the average as summing value I get number one only

What I get is this:

```
Month   Transfers  Average 
June    1          1
July    2          1
August  1          1
```

Whereas it should be something like

```
Month   Transfers  Average
June    1          0.333
July    2          0.667
August  1          0.333
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can use the code button for fixed formatting, I've fixed it for you. :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "count sum" column. Usually they are either count or sum, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the 'calculated field' functionality. Go to the Pivot Table "Options" when you highlight the pivot table in the ribbon and click on "formulas"

[image]

Then the calculated field option. Which presents you with the following:

[image]

Name your field 'average' and then write the formula required. To reference a field already in the pivot you need to enclose the field name in **'**

So your formula would look like:

```
='Month'/30
```

Click OK to add it and you end up with a calculated field attached to the pivot table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you have MONTH in Row Labels, and a COUNT/SUM of TRANSFERS in Values.

- Add an additional COUNT/SUM of TRANSFERS in Values, to make a duplicate.
- Click on Value Field Settings for that new count
- Go in the "Show Value As" Tab
- Change Normal to % of Column

This will always show a grand total of 100%, or all your transfers (4).